# Jquery, alter image

Tags: jquery

I know that I can use $('#myId').load('aPage.html'); to load a page into an element, how do I do use that to alter an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("selectorforyourimage").attr("src","newimagelocation");
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the image will load no sooner, than you load it, so you may want to **preload** it.

For this, you can use [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Preload) or [this mini-plugin](http://www.mattfarina.com/2007/02/01/preloading_images_with_jquery)